# AngularJS - Binding same scope to multiple copies of a form using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I have a simple search form which I have it included in two different pages using **ng-include** directive. I would like to bind them both to the same scope in such a way that when the user navigates between the pages, they'll keep seeing the same search data they've entered in either of the copies.

I have managed to implement an untidy solution using rootScope, but would like to know if this can be implemented in a proper, cleaner way?

Comment: Use an angular service to share data and common methods between them

Answer (score 0):

I also used root scope slove it, my layout below:

```
<div id="page-header" ng-include="'views/layouts/header.html'"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div ui-view="content" ng-cloak></div>
</div>
<div id="page-footer" ng-include="'views/layouts/footer.html'"></div>
<div id="toastElement">
    <ul id="toastBox"></ul>
</div>
```

header.html bound HeaderController, the functions in HeaderController include search, login, logout, register and both working on $rootScope. Is it helpful?